# Using Hive SQLContext in spark executors

Tags: python, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am getting a complex json message through kafka. I need to extract the required fields from the json and store them in hive tables. I know I cannot use the spark driver sqlContext in the executors. I want to know how to use the sqlContext in the code run by the executors. Here is the code :

```
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming", topic)
msgs = kvs.map(lambda msg: msg[1])
msgs.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreach(lambda m : timeline_events(m)))


def timeline_events(m):
   msg = json.loads(m)
   for msgJson in msg:
       event_id = msgJson['events'][0]['event_id']
       event_type = msgJson['events'][0]['type']
       incidence_source = msgJson['incident']['source']
       csr_description = msgJson['incident']['data']['csr_description']
       sc_display_priority = msgjson['incident']['data']['display_priority']
       launch_tool_rec_label = msgJson['incident']['data']['LaunchTool'][0]['Label']
       launch_tool_rec_uri =  msgJson['incident']['data']['LaunchTool'][0]['URI']
       launch_itg_rec_label = msgJson['incident']['data']['LaunchItg'][0]['Label']
       launch_itg_rec_uri =  msgJson['incident']['data']['LaunchItg'][0]['URI']
       sqlContext.sql("Insert into nexus.timeline_events values({},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{})".format(event_id, event_type, csr_description, incidence_source, sc_display_priority, launch_tool_rec_label,launch_tool_rec_uri, launch_tool_rec_id, launch_itg_rec_label, launch_itg_rec_uri, launch_itg_rec_id))
```